# Writing Output to a File

Tags: c#

How do I write some `Console.WriteLine()` values to a file located in `C:\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `StreamWriter` class:

```
var outputfile = new StreamWriter("c:\\outputfile.txt");
outputfile.Writeline("some text"); 
outputfile.Close();
```

However, depending on your version of Windows, you might not have permission to write to C:\.

Answer (score 10):

- `app.exe > c:\somefile.txt`

or

- `Console.SetOut(File.CreateText("c:\\somefile.txt"));`

Comment: Seems everyone was too eager to answer, and did not read the question correctly, try again :)

Comment: While I do agree with you leppie that you've answered the actual question (so +1), it's a bit terse for what's apparently a novice OP. Also, should be just answer blindly or should we be looking to educate, in which may be we should be asking questions in case the actual approach is invalid and there's a better solution that you are aware of.

Comment: @Lazarus: If you go back to most of my answers, I never give the entire answer (aka spoonfeed). IMO, it is important to further research an answer to understand it completely, else I would just be encouraging copy-paste code. I know many wont agree with my approach, but that is the way I learned the ins and outs.

Comment: I'm very much behind the breadcrumb approach where appropriate. I guess it's whether you believe the OP will follow the breadcrumb or just eat it ;) May be you just need to point out that it's a breadcrumb. Just observation, not meant as hard criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/DemonstratesredirectingtheConsoleoutputtoafile.htm) is what you want?

Comment: Your answer could be better if you had included relevant code snippets from that link rather than just posting the link alone.

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks for advice!

Comment: One more thing, and summarize too.  Why wait til next time? You can edit it in right now.  :)

Comment: Yeah but the solution I found has already received 9 votes up. BTW it's strange that it's not a solution to a question even though for majority the right answer is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

use `StreamWriter` for writing with `using`, which ensures the correct usage of `IDisposable` objects.

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\filename"))
    {
        writer.Write("some text");
        writer.WriteLine("some other text");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\1.txt");
        sw.WriteLine("Hi");
        sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        sw.Close();
```

and do not forget to use System.IO

```
       using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to log some data. Rather than calling `Console.WriteLine()` directly, you should just use some kind of delegate to output to both the file and console.

```
Action<string> log = Console.WriteLine;
log += str => File.AppendText("c:\\file.log", str + Environment.Newline);

log("LOG ME");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a System.IO.File class. It has a lot of useful methods for file manipulation, like File.WriteAllLines(fileName) for example.